# How can I open a temporary buffer

Tags: emacs

For very long time I have done: <kbd>C-x b</kbd> and then some "unique" name like `xbxb`. So I use  `switch-to-buffer` with a non-existent buffer. You can imagine what <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> shows me: Lots of such names. `xbxb`, `xbxbxxx` .... It really gets annoying after some time (a week or so), since I discover that I have already used all good names.

Is there a more canonical way of opening a new buffer? If I want to run a shell a further time, I say <kbd>C-u M-x shell</kbd>.  Something along that line would be ideal.

Comment: do you really need all those temporary buffers? My strategy is to have a single buffer like this named "tmp". When I need it I switch to it, then either delete whatever is there or append to it.

Comment: Sometimes I do and sometimes I don't ...

Answer (score 17):

You can use `make-temp-name` to generate a name for a file or buffer with a random postfix.  With that as a base, you can write something like this:

```
(defun generate-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (make-temp-name "scratch")))
```

where "scratch" can be replaced by whatever prefix you'd like.

Comment: +1 too! Will have to wait to see if there is an existing command **somehow**!

Answer (score 7):

make it so:

```
(defun new-scratch ()
  "open up a guaranteed new scratch buffer"
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (loop for num from 0
                          for name = (format "blah-%03i" num)
                          while (get-buffer name)
                          finally return name)))
```

Comment: Instead of `(loop ...)` rather `generate-new-buffer-name`. But isn't there already a command for that - somehow? +1 in any case.

Comment: didn't know about `generate-new-buffer-name`, but there s no command AFAIK.

Comment: Evaluating the function definition and then running it interactively results in *Symbol's definition is void: new-scratch*.

Answer (score 4):

I signed up just to answer this question (because I use this function a lot, so I thought it'd be useful to share it here):

```
(defun tmpbuf (buf)
  "open a buffer,
if it doesn't exist, open a new one"
  (interactive "sBuffer name: ")
  (switch-to-buffer
   (get-buffer-create (concat "*" buf "*"))))
```

Comment: I do not understand the difference between your command and `C-x b` that is `switch-to-buffer` except that you will bracket the buffer name with * *.

Comment: The difference between `switch-to-buffer` and `get-buffer-create` is `get-buffer-create` will just create a buffer but won't change to it. Whereas `switch-to-buffer` will try to switch to a buffer, if no such buffer exists, it'll prompt you. I get a bit pedantic, so I use `interactive` with parameter `s` which prompts you for the buffer name from the start. So I guess if you just need a buffer that you'll write to and then won't care for then *R. P. Dillon's* answer is great.

Comment: I just wish to have temporary buffers with a particular name. Lets say I'm working on cars, I'll create a temp buffer named `*cars*`, jot stuff down and move to a different buffer and do some work there. So if I need to check my notes on cars, I know the buffer is named `*cars*`. If you use a set buffer prefix, like **R.P. Dillon** shows above, then you'll have too many buffers with the same prefix... it wouldn't be easy to tell them apart at a quick glance.

Comment: But ... you can do exactly this with `C-x b` already!  What I very often encounter is that I want to have this buffer **now** prior to thinking whether its about cars or cdrs. When it gets "more serious", I do `M-x rename-buffer`.

Comment: I was saying that my function creates buffers that you choose the name for. If there is too many buffers that start with "scratch..." then it's no so easy to tell them apart on a first glance...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you want. You say that "I discover that I have already used all good names", so letting Emacs generate the names isn't going to be any good, but if you are going to specify the name yourself, it doesn't get any more canonical than <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> `name` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Otherwise, one of the functions already suggested to let you enter a string and use that with some kind of "tmp buffer" pattern to create a new name would seem sensible.

Or [scratch.el](https://github.com/ieure/scratch-el) might prove useful, if what you actually wanted was a single temp buffer per major mode.

You could almost certainly benefit from binding <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd> to `ibuffer`, and using filters and/or groups to separate out the temporary buffers from the more important ones. That would deal with the list getting cluttered.

You seem oddly resistant to writing a new function? Even if there did turn out to be something built in, there's nothing *wrong* with using custom functions -- that's generally how you go about customising Emacs to your liking.

Comment: I am very resistant to writing a new function. Not that I never had, but since I want to share an environment with others. Otherwise I am entirely stranded on a different machine. I expect something like `C-u C-x C-b`.

Comment: What I meant with having used "all good names": These are the unique names I type in like `df` `asdf` `asdfff` etc.

Comment: re: being "stranded", have you considered putting your configuration into version control? Lots of people do that, and it really is a fantastic solution. Everywhere you go you just pull down your own config and you're ready to go. You can make changes to your config anywhere and push them to the central repository, and then pull them back down when you move back to another machine.

Comment: I am very well aquainted to the `C-x v` prefix. But the situation, where this comes up is when I type into the emacs of someone else. I do not dare to "pull down" my own config there. Often, I don't even type but tell them to type.

Comment: Right, that makes more sense. (Although given that *they* might have their own custom config, you might still run into similar problems; but I do see where you're coming from, now.)

Comment: Coming back to this decade-old question (it just got bumped, and I found that the answer I agreed with was written by me), it's probably worth emphasising that the real solution is to stop using `df`, `asdf`, `asdfff`, and other such nonsense names, unless you're planning to kill the buffer almost immediately.  Those are categorically *not* "good names".  Take 2-3 seconds to type something that is even vaguely descriptive, and your entire problem\* goes away. ([\*] A problem which *cannot* in any case be solved by code which has no idea what you're wanting the temporary buffer for.)

Comment: somewhat related is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21247494/772868) insight I got 2 years later (and after a quarter century of Emacs-use).

Answer (score 3):

```el
(defun yashi/new-scratch-buffer-in-org-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer-name "*temp*"))
  (org-mode))
(bind-key "<f7>" 'yashi/new-scratch-buffer-in-org-mode)
```

I'm using [deft](http://jblevins.org/projects/deft/) for a quick note-taking but sometimes I know I won't need the content but need a buffer in Org mode.  For that, it's been serving me well.  Hit <kbd>F7</kbd> again will create a buffer with similar name, `*temp*<2>` in my case, acording to [Uniquify](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html).

BTW, here is a command to launch a new buffer with a new deft file, if you are interested.  <kbd>F6</kbd> to launch it.

```
(defun yashi/deft-new-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((deft-filter-regexp nil))
    (deft-new-file)))
(bind-key "<f6>" 'yashi/deft-new-file)
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this to open up a temporary buffer. Good thing? Helps me track which buffers I'd opened, and when.

```el
(defun tmp-buffer()
      "Make a temporary buffer and switch to it - Like C-n for Sublime etc"
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (concat "tmp-" (format-time-string "%m.%dT%H.%M.%S")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are given access to [someone else's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363982/how-can-i-open-a-temporary-buffer/35450574#comment13375084_10369801) Emacs and you want to open a new buffer. If you are lucky, this someone has set `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to `t`. If not, you can temporarily do <kbd>M-:</kbd> to eval this Emacs Lisp expression (don't forget to restore this parameter later):

```
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
```

Now, you open a new buffer:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> prompts for a buffer name
- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-:</kbd> will eval and print the result of the expression to the minibuffer prompt:

  ```
  (random)
  ```
- This gives you a random number in the full range of representable integers (including negative ones), which is very unlikely to be already taken. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> to conclude to switch to the new buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for which I have the freedom to give a name or it randomly generates a name. I merged the [andswer of @dotemacs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366282/1613005) and the [answer of R. P. Dillon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365481/1613005). I'm a n00b in elisp so it took me some half an hour to resolve some of my stupid mistakes.

```el
(defun mm/generate-temp-buffer (buf)
  "A function to generate temprory buffers using either
a random name or given name"
  (interactive "sNew temp buffer name: ")
  (switch-to-buffer
   (get-buffer-create
    (concat "*tmp*"
            (if (equal buf "")
                (make-temp-name "")
              buf)
            "*")
    )))
```

This is how it works:

1. you run the function (`M-x mm/generate-temp-buffer`)
2. you are asked for a name.
   2.1. if you type something it will create a buffer named `*tmp*YOUR_STRING*`
   2.2. if you don't give an input and just press RET, it will create a buffer named something like `*tmp*o8f4Mf*`

Hopefully this is useful to others and save someone's time.